# python библиотека для скачивания torrents

Tags: python-3.x

Подскажите какие есть библиотеки для скачивания торрент-файлов (когда уже есть файл с разрешением .torrent и нужно скачать то что он в себе хранит) для Python 3?

Comment: Для скачивания торрент-файлов, или для скачевания торрентов?

Answer (score 1):

Есть библиотека [python-bittorent](https://github.com/JosephSalisbury/python-bittorrent)

Но ее не поддерживают около 6 лет. Тем не менее она умеет качать содержимое торрентов и создавать торрент файлы. Если вам не принципиально использовать библиотеку для питона, то ,возможно, более хорошим решением будет запускать торрент через какой-нибудь известный торрент-клиент, передавая файл как аргумент коммандной строки. Например, так:

`uTorrent.exe "mytorrent.torrent"`